# How to select unique values from one column based on a value in another column?

Tags: mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

The structure of the table is that a value in the `child_id` column can be duplicated *but* has a different associated `parent_id` for each duplicate. Say `child_id` **1** has four parents, then it will have 3 copies of itself in the `child_id` column, but each duplicate is associated with each of the 3 different `parent_id`.

Given those conditions, what I'm trying to achieve is to sort by `parent_id` and remove the unwanted `child_id` duplicates by picking only one  based on the last or closest  parent (level of that parent would be -1 the level of the child). Is that possible?

I tried to create a fiddle on sqlfiddle but I keep getting a *create script error* so I guess I'll just paste the code here:

```
CREATE TABLE `parent_child_columns` (`id` int auto_increment,
                                     `child_id` int,
                                       `parent_id` int,
                                     `level` int,
                                     PRIMARY KEY (`id`))

INSERT INTO `parent_child_columns` (`child_id`, `parent_id`, `level`)
VALUES (1, 0, 1), (2, 0, 1),
       (3, 1, 2), (4, 1, 2),
       (5, 3, 3), (5, 1, 3), (6, 3, 3), (6, 1, 3)



SELECT pc.child_id, pc.level
FROM parent_child_columns pc
ORDER BY pc.parent_id
```

With this query, the duplicates still get picked up so a column is already displayed before another one when it should come AFTER that other one (since its level 1 parent is at the top when sorted ASC). (A parent column can have many child columns.) I can include screencaps of the actual data in my database if necessary.

I'm building a dynamic table header here where you can add an indefinite number of nested columns. There's a bit more stuff going on with how I arrange the rows and columns so if my explanation here is still a bit vague and you can't get a clear picture, please let me know. But a rundown of what I do is basically I try to build row by row and arrange the columns in each child level (or row) based on the order of the parent columns right above them.

What I'm getting:
[image]
[image]

Expected output is that in the actual table, **1843** should be under **1842**, as seen in the database that its parents are **1839** and **1842**. I'm only assuming that it's already under **1841** because it gets picked up earlier, but maybe that's not actually the case? Any better ideas as to what might be causing that?

P.S. In the example above I tried to split **1841** so it should have the 2 New Columns under it.

Comment: Please edit your question and show the desired results as well as the sample data.

Comment: What would the result look like?

Comment: possible distinct solves the problem? SELECT distinct ...

Comment: Your structure may make sense to you, but what does `parent_id` refer to?  `child_id` or `id`?

Comment: Basically the parent-child relationship is in one table. `parent_id` refers to another `child_id` in that table. @GordonLinoff

Comment: @Strawberry I'll try to reproduce what I encountered (I thought I saved it but turns out I didn't). Basically one of the newly inserted columns was misplaced.

Comment: I've updated my question @GordonLinoff

Comment: I've updated my question @Strawberry

Answer (score 0):

If you want the parent with "-1" the level of the child, then use `join`:

```
SELECT pc.*, pcp.id
FROM parent_child_columns pc LEFT JOIN
     parent_child_columns pcp
     ON pc.parent_id = pcp.child_id AND pcp.level = pc.level - 1
ORDER BY pc.parent_id;
```